# Constructing dataframe with position of elements order of occurrence

Tags: r

Can anyone please help on building a matrix that holds sequential positions using R as below :

Source Data:

```
sampledata <- data.frame("column1" = c("a","b","c","d","e","a","b","e"),
    "column2" = c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0))
```

Resultant Matrix:

[image: Result]

Logic in constructing the result matrix: Consider step =3. From the actual data consider first 3 rows a,b,c and yes/no column has one 'Yes'. So the respective values of a,b,c,d,e,f in the resultant matrix is filled as, the order in which a,b,c are occuring in the source data and the values are filled as 1,2,3,0,0,0 with Yes. The next step has b,c,d so the resultant matrix is filled as 0,1,2,3,0,0 with Yes. This process should be repeated until the last sequence in the source data.

Can anyone please help me in doing the above.

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sampledata <- data.frame("column1" = c("a","b","c","d","e","a","b","e"),
                         "column2" = c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0))

step = 3
v <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")

# allocate memory for the resulting matrix
result <- matrix(0, 
                 nrow = nrow(sampledata) - step + 1, 
                 ncol = length(v) + 1)
colnames(result) <- c(v, "Yes.No")

for (i in 1 : (nrow(sampledata) - step + 1 )){

  # find position of every letter in the vector v within subset of column1
  pos <- match( v, sampledata$column1[i : (i + step - 1)])

  # change NAs to 0
  pos[is.na(pos)] <- 0

  # fill the row with the values in pos and sum of values in column 2
  result[i,] <- c(pos, sum(sampledata$column2[i : (i + step - 1)]))
}


result
#     a b c d e f Yes.No
#[1,] 1 2 3 0 0 0      1
#[2,] 0 1 2 3 0 0      1
#[3,] 0 0 1 2 3 0      1
#[4,] 3 0 0 1 2 0      1
#[5,] 2 3 0 0 1 0      0
#[6,] 1 2 0 0 3 0      0
```

Comment: @user080391 You are welcome.  If this  answers your question - please check the answer "accepted".

Comment: I have a small concern when I increasing step > 3 the Yes.No column is displaying 2's as well.. It worked well with step <= 3 .. can you please look into the issue

Comment: I figured it out.. i changed "result[i,] <- c(pos, sum(sampledata$column2[i : (i + step - 1)]))" to "result[i,] <- c(pos, sum(unique(sampledata$column2[i : (i + step - 1)])))"

Comment: @user080391 Right, in your original question it was not clear if you need to calculate the number of 1s or the presence of at least one of them. If you just want to see if there is at least one "yes", then you can use your own solution or cummax(sampledata$column2[i : (i + step - 1)])